# Why do I get not allowed access when using keycloak JavaScript adapter?

Tags: javascript, django, keycloak

I have a Django app authenticating via Keycloak as described [here](http://blog.jonharrington.org/static/integrate-django-with-keycloak/). From this Django app I now wants to call a microservice also protected by Keycloak using the same login. I don't want the suer to have to login again. I am trying to yse the [JavaScript adapter](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html). I am trying to configure it something like:

```
  <script>
    var keycloak = Keycloak({
        url: "{{Keycloakurl}}/auth",
        realm: 'myrealm',
        clientId: 'myclient'
    });
    keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(function(authenticated) {
        alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failed to initialize');
    });
  </script>
```

But when I load the page I get this sort of error messages:

`Failed to load http://keycloak.FOO.com/auth/realms/toxhq/protocol/openid-connect/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myapp.Foo.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am not fully sure why this is but I am beginning to wonder if it is because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in some way.

How can I set up the functionality I want with Keycloak protected microservices sharing one Keycloak authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the allowed origin for `myclient`in the Keycloak console. (check the last input box on the client details screen)